# VSCode tasks.json args

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have looked into a lot of posts before I clicked "Ask" button, but it seems no one mentions this barrier.

I followed what this doc says: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw#_next-steps

But when it comes to `Modifying tasks.json`, which is posted in `Build helloworld.cpp`, I found it not work no matter how I modify the `args`. When I tried modifying the `label` of `tasks.json`, the label that I can view when I click to config the task changed.

[image]

All I want to do is just set the name of the output exe file to the workspaceFolder's name.